# Pygame.not getting value for one of axes on the joystick

Tags: python, pygame, joystick

I am using Pygame to get values from a Simraceway steering wheel, which is just seen as a joystick. There are three axes on the joystick -- one for steering, one for the left paddle, and one for the right paddle.

When I do the Pygame command `get_numaxes()`, I correctly get back 3 axes. But when I do the command `get_axis(1)`, which should return the value for the left paddle, I do not get the correct value. I do get the correct values for `get_axis(0)` (the steering) and `get_axis(2)` (the right paddle).

In Windows, the left paddle shows up as Z-rotation rather than a normal axis. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Why is `get_axis(1)` not getting the position of the left paddle? Is there any program other than Pygame that will work better at getting a Z-rotation axis from this joystick, like Windows does?

Comment: What kind of incorrect values are you getting for the left paddle? Does the value change when you move the paddle but not match what you expect? Is it a constant value as if representing a different axis?

Comment: The left paddle axis stays constant at -1 even when I press it. The right paddle axis ranges correctly from -1 to 1 as I press it from minimum to maximum.

Comment: I consider this unlikely, but is it possible something else on that wheel is counting as the 3rd axis instead of the left paddle? I.E. press every button, move it every way possible and be certain there is no response anywhere on get_axis(1)?

Comment: Good question. There is nothing on the wheel that could be mistaken as the third axis. All the other controls are buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out why `get_axis(1)` did not get the position of the left paddle.

However, I was able to use `evdev` to get all the information I need from the steering wheel. It's not very high level, unlike Pygame, but it does work.